# Arcmap: save all layers in Table of Contents to layer files

Tags: python, arcmap

Using python, how can one save all layers in the Arcmap (v10) table of contents pane to layer files on disk?

Comment: The [arcpy.mapping](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000032000000) module documentation should have examples on how to do this.

Comment: Hello I'm trying to do the same thing but I have and error with layer from server, how can I pick only .shp files in my mxd? Thanks a lot Luca

Comment: Hi @Luca, I'm not sure. The exact error message would be likely useful in figuring that out. Might be worth posting as a separate question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Untested since I'm not in front of ArcGIS at the moment, but you should be able to use the `Layer.saveACopy(path)` method. For example:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    lyr.saveACopy(lyr.name + ".lyr")
```

Comment: that works, thank you! Two caveats: `env.workspace` is ignored, the layer files are saved in the same folder as the .mxd, and group layers are ignored (though their contents are still saved, individually)

Comment: glad to hear it! Strange that it doesn't export group layers though.